# Using ASP.NET Variable in Javascript inside UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a javascript function inside UpdatePanel. The variable should  be updated on UpdatePanel partial postback.

Using the below code, the javascript variable jsonStringASPX will always have the initial value, regardless of what JsonString ASP.NET variable has.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function pageLoad(){
    LoadExpenseList(); 
}
</script>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
<ContentTemplate>
<script type="text/javascript">

         function LoadExpenseList() {
         var jsonStringASPX = <%= JsonString %>; 
        var jsonHeaderStringASPX = <%= JsonHeaderString %>; 
    //Works with the Strings
    }
</script>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Maybe if you show the code-behind the question will be more clear?

Comment: When is `LoadExpenseList();` called? It must also be triggered after UpdatePanel update (I think, but as @barrypicker mentioned there is little to go on).

Comment: @VDWWD Its called from pageLoad function. pageLoad function triggers after every postback (partial or full)

Comment: After your post back, reset the value JsonString and JsonHeaderString and call the LocalExpenseList again use Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock